# Creating a flexbox navbar with a logo in the center and list items to the left and right

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I've been banging my head against this for a good while now. I thought it would be simple, but... it's not.

My thought process and code.

The HTML

```
      <nav className="navbar">
        <div className="left">
          <ul>
            <li>HOME</li>
            <li>ARTISTS</li>
            <li>MEDIA</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="center">
          <img src={logo} alt="" />
        </div>
        <div className="right">
          <ul>
            <li>MERCHANDISE</li>
            <li>FAMILY</li>
            <li>CONTACT</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

The CSS (Sass):

```
$black: #000;
$white: #fff;

html,
body {
  background-color: $black !important;
  color: $white;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 120px;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

So basically, the logo in the middle is never perfectly centered. No matter what I do. I can of course add some extra margin to make it centered, but that's just adding some more problems later on.

The items to the right, with className 'right' are also just pushed to the right because the length of the words is different.

I'm wondering if flexbox is the way to go for a simple navbar like this or not?

Does the fact that this gets wrapped in a div in React also mess with things? (Although it doesn't have a specific class).

Seems like everything I find online is either Bootstrap solutions or a completely different way that, as soon as you a different menu item, messes with the whole navbar.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track!

Try:

```
    nav {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .center, .left, .right {
        flex: 1;
    }
    nav ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    nav ul li {
        display: inline;
        padding: 30px;
    }
```

I gave the `nav` a `width:100%;` so the `flex:1` can take as much room as it's allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is really simple, please follow this:

```js
const App = () => {

 return ( 
  <div className="App">
    <nav className="navbar">
      <div className="left">
        <ul className="list">
          <li>HOME</li>
          <li>ARTISTS</li>
          <li>MEDIA</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="center">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div className="right">
        <ul className="list">
          <li>MERCHANDISE</li>
          <li>FAMILY</li>
          <li>CONTACT</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
   </div>
 )
}

ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: .25rem;
}

.list li {
  padding: .25rem
}

/* make it responsive */
@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
 .navbar {
   flex-direction: column;
 }
 .list {
   flex-direction: column;
   text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: For some reason the logo in the center is still not perfectly centered. To be clear, it's a .png file with no margins or whatever, so it should be centered perfectly. Should the logo be a certain size perhaps?

Comment: That's because it will depends on the `left, right` width, I guess maybe `position: absolute` is better in this case.

Comment: I haven't changed anything and this is the result: https://imgur.com/mW5k2RM

Comment: Position absolute (on the img tag you meant probably?) just puts the logo in front of the banner image, but still not perfectly centered for some reason... 
Thank you for the help uptil now in any case.

Comment: Ah i see, you mean not centered to the image container? if so, you may need to set the width for the `div` that wrap your nav. take a look at this [sandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-elion-v6hcc)